# Yii some users can't login

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, yii2

So I've been assigned to fix one of our older webapps which uses Yii, And we dev isn't available anymore.

**I'm not a Yii dev, I have no idea what I'm doing**

But anyway, I tried and failed...

### The issue is the following:

Most of our older users can login, but the new ones can't.
What happens is when they try to login they first login, and then *(I think)* when they should be redirected to the home page by `return $this->goHome();` it get's redirected to login. So after this, the login page sends them back to the homepage. (since they are logged in at this point)  After 10 of this the page displays the too many redirects error.

### What I've tried:

I changed goBack to goHome, because I tought maybe it doesn't know where to send the user thatt's why it happens. No luck....

```
public function actionLogin() {
      if (!Yii::$app->getUser()->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
      }

        $this->layout = "@app/views/layouts/loginscreen.php";

        $model = new Login();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            return $this->render('login', [
                        'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I edited the .htaccess, but that didn't work nor would that explain why older users can login.

### What I have as info:

- Older users can login. (not sure how far back)
- The app has been copied to a different server,
  but we still use the old one.
- After trying to login with a new user I can't load in the page at all, unless I delete the cookies.
- The cookies set to never exipre.

web configs user relatered things:

```
'user' => [
    'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
    'loginUrl' => ['admin/user/login'],
    'on ' . \yii\web\User::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN => ['app\events\UserLoginEvents', 'AfterLogin'],
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
],
```

After login is maybe custom:

```
namespace app\events;

use Yii;

class UserLoginEvents {

    public static function AfterLogin($event) {

        $session = Yii::$app->session;
        $session->updateUser(Yii::$app->getUser()->id);

        if (!trim($event->identity->getAuthKey())) {
            $event->identity->generateAuthKey();
            $event->identity->save();
            Yii::$app->getUser()->switchIdentity ( $event->identity, $event->duration );
        }

    }

}
```

**Thank You** for your help in advance. We really don't have anyone to go to, so I'm kind of a last resort.. And not a very good one at that either.

> I have ssh access to the server phpmyadmin access to the db, and I
>   have the code, but not the git just from ftp.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is in the goback

`return $this->goBack();`

it is say go to the previous page, so go again in login page, this because you are inside the login page, then you posting inside the login page and then you say to go again in login page.

try with different code:

`return $this->redirect(['/site/index']);`

By the way it is alway better to use the syntax above, because some server, specially new one, can not have history for redirect

Comment: Server does not have a "history for redirect", `goBack()` redirects to page set in session when user tries to access page available only for logged users. It has nothing to do with server "age".

Comment: I do not remember now, maybe was not the server but some PHP extension not anymore available. It is something about security. I had problem with goBack() for that reason